# Rails: Bootstrap dropdown menu not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am quite new to Rails and have been following the tutorial by Michael Hartl.  Everything has been going along really well until I got to the drop down menu, which was wasn't working, then was working and now isn't working :(  I've read several posts and fixes and I suspect my tinkering has gotten to the point where quite simply, I've done something to stop it working.
I will say that I initially had the bootstrap-sass 2.x in my gem file, then changed it to 3.x, but went back to 2.x because I didn't realise that going to 3.x would result in issues due to class name changes.  So, perhaps the time this was working was when I had bootstrap-sass 3.x installed, not sure.  From what I can tell though everything is set up the way it needs to be.  I am developing under Windows 8.1 and I had to fix an issue with execjs and in specific the runtimes.rb file.  So, here are my details:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.15'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '1.2'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

_header.html.erb (where the drop down is)

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Catered Fit", root_path, id: "logo" %>
<!--      <%= link_to image_tag("logo.jpg", width: "25%"), root_path %>    -->
      <nav>
        <div class="nav pull-right">
<!--          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>   -->
          <% if !signed_in? %>
            <div class="navbar-form">
            <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
              <div class="span2 input-xlarge">
                <% f.label :email %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
              </div>
              <div class="span2 input-small">
                <% f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %>
              </div>
              <div class="span2">
                <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>  
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I don't see any errors in the console window and apart from the drop down everything else is working fine.

The following is the source code from the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Dave Williams</title>
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="SlKTCvDr5MFLP0EkthJHQeGIw+Yp0oGUrxvAeQMnVts=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="/" id="logo">Catered Fit</a>
<!--      <a href="/"><img alt="Logo" src="/assets/logo.jpg" width="25%" /></a>    -->
      <nav>
        <div class="nav pull-right">
<!--          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>   -->
            <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/users/1">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/users/1/edit">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <a data-method="delete" href="/signout" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <li><a data-method="delete" href="/signout" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a></li>
            </li>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <img alt="Dave Williams" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/387593e03fccc38895fc20a2084e27f5?s=50" />
        Dave Williams
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>

      <footer class="footer">
  <small>
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Rails Tutorial</a>
    by Michael Hartl
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
      <pre class="debug_dump">--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
action: show
controller: users
id: &#39;1&#39;
</pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would really appreciate some help on this to get past this issue.

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if I can provide anymore information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was able to determine was the issue was 2 rouge js files that I had placed in the assets/javascript directory.  Namely, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js.  Once I removed these files the dropdown was working again.

Comment: May be the issue is rails loading all bootstrap assets twice.

Answer (score 5):

I changed the order of directives in app/assets/javascripts/application.js to:
`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .`

Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Odd it hasn't been fixed yet. But this solution worked for me as well. I had to add    //= require turbolinks between bootstrap and require_tree as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to call it via javascript adding :

```
<script>
   $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```

at the botton of your _header file.

hope helps!

Comment: I tried every solution here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/714 ++ at least 10 others. none of them worked. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is bootstrap's javascript. Sometimes is loaded two times.

This works to me:

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
```

application.scss: Don't use //= require in scss files

```
@import "*";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Then:

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```

**OR**

Put bootstrap.js in assets/javascripts folder and put **//= require_tree .**   line

Answer (score 0):

Using a later version of rails (5.2.3) I found that the instructions given in the book didn't work. The console warned me that jQuery needed to be installed, and by going to https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails I was able to find the instructions to get it up-and-running.

Add to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Add to application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
```

So that the whole Gemfile is

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern version of the book (rails 6+) this is what i've done to make it work:

In app/javascript/packs/application.js change the order of

```
require("jquery");
import "bootstrap";
```

to be before turbolinks - so final implementation of application.js looks like:

```
require("jquery");
import "bootstrap";
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
```

Book shows to add jquery & bootstrap at the end after turbolinks - what in my opinion causes the problem. Thanks!