# Rails 4 - which order to put jQuery and bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to figure out how to load assets in my application.js.

I have these required files (among others) in my application.js.

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
```

My gem file has:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

When bootstrap-sprockets is before jQuery, then my bootstrap dropdown menu (below) works fine.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:30px">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8">
        <% if policy(@project).show? %>    

            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" style="color: black" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                STATUS: <%= text_for_state(@project.current_state) %> <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <% if policy(@project).request_preapproval? %>    
                    <%= link_to "REQUEST APPROVAL", request_preapproval_project_path(@project), method: :put, :style=>"padding-left:20px; padding-right: 10px" %>
                <% end %>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <% if policy(@project).publish? %>    
                    <%= link_to "PUBLISH", publish_project_path(@project),  method: :put, :style=>"padding-left:20px; padding-right: 10px" %>
                <% end %>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                <!-- <a href="#" class='btn btn-primary'>REQUEST MORE INFORMATION</a> -->
                <% if policy(@project).update? %>

                    <%= link_to "EDIT PROJECT", edit_project_path(@project), :style=>"padding-left:20px; padding-right: 10px" %>
                <% end %>

                 <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <% if policy(@project).edit? %>    
                    <%= link_to "REMOVE", edit_project_path(@project), :style=>"padding-left:20px; padding-right: 10px" %>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>


        <% end %>
    </div>    
</div
```

However, in that case, my tab show function on the following setup doesnt work. I can't click on the tabs. If I move jQuery above bootstrap-sprockets, it does work, but then the drop down menu, which otherwise works, stops working.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="dp-tab-1">
                        <ul class="dp-tab-list row" id="myTab">
                            <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 active" >
                                <a href="#tab-guag-content-first">
                                    <span>MOTIVATION</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#tab-guag-content-second">
                                    <span>OBJECTIVES</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#tab-guag-content-third">
                                    <span>VISION</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                        <div class="dp-tab-content tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane row fade in active" id="tab-guag-content-first">

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="tab-inner">

                                        <p class='medium-text'>
                                            <%= @project.motivation %>
                                        </p>
                                        <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane row fade" id="tab-guag-content-second">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="tab-inner">
                                        <p class='medium-text'>
                                            <%= @project.objective %>
                                        </p>
                                        <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <img class='wow fadeInUp img-responsive' src="images/iphone-mockup.png" alt=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane row fade" id="tab-guag-content-third">

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="tab-inner">
                                        <div class='services-content'>
                                            <strong>Long Term Research Vision</strong>
                                            <p class='medium-text'>
                                                <%= @long_term %>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='services-content'>
                                            <strong>Immediate Challenge</strong>    
                                            <p class='medium-text'>
                                                <%= @immediate_challenge %>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>    
                                        <br/>
                                        <!-- <a class='btn btn-primary'>READ MORE</a> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
            <!-
```

When I try to render the page in the case when bootstrap is loaded before jQuery, I get this error in the chrome inspector console tab:

```
main.self-9711b4c….js?body=1:56 Uncaught TypeError: dp(...).tab is not a function(anonymous function) @ main.self-9711b4c….js?body=1:56dispatch @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:5227elemData.handle @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:4879
```

How can I solve this so that I can have both the drop down and the tabs working?

My entire application.js is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require html.sortable
//= require disqus_rails
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require masonry.pkgd.min
//= require multipleFilterMasonry
//= require main
//= require hammer.min
//= require jquery.animate-enhanced.min
//= require jquery.countTo
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require jquery.fitvids
//= require jquery.magnific-popup.min
//= require jquery.parallax-1.1.3
//= require jquery.properload
//= require jquery.shuffle.modernizr.min
//= require jquery.sudoSlider.min
//= require jquery.superslides.min
//= require rotaterator
//= require smoothscrolljs
//= require waypoints.min
//= require wow.min
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require markerclusterer
//= require infobox
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require cocoon
//= require imagesloaded.pkgd.min
//= require isotope.pkgd.min
//= require jquery.counterup.min
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require custom.js
//= require slider
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require_tree .
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I have tried all of the suggestions in this post: none of them work for me: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/714

Answer (score 3):

Works perfectly.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui 
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

You have defined bootstrap.js before the jquery. but in every application you should defined jquery at the top, so it would be load first.

Comment: Hi @Prashant - thanks for the note. That doesnt work unfortunately. It works fine with the tabs, but it means the bootstrap dropdown menu doesnt work. There are no errors showing in the chrome inspector console, and I can see the drop down menu elements in the chrome inspector, although the button that is supposed to reveal the drop down menu does nothing. The menu doesnt work. It does work, however, if I put bootstrap above jQuery. If I do that, then the tabs in the later html doesnt work.

Comment: Can you please check with ctrl +u on web to check order of js and also check is there any conflict i.e duplicate js initialize in your app.
and you can put //= require bootstrap-sprockets just down the //= require jquery

Comment: Hi Prahsant. Please could you give me a bit more detail about what to check. How do I check the order of the js? Im on a mac - ctrl u does nothing. Also, could you clarify what you mean by putting bootstrap-sprockets just down means. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Ya sure, I am here to help you. I meant your browser page where you are accessing your app. So you should use ctrl + u so this will show you all js and css which includes in your app and their front end html also. 
My second point put //= require bootstrap-sprockets at 2 position. and you can try with remove  //= require jquery-ui 
//= require jquery_ujs atleast once.

Comment: can you please try with remove //= require_tree . at the bottom of you application.js

Comment: please try with only //= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui 
//= require bootstrap-sprockets and removes everything in application.js, it must helpful

Comment: When I remove require jquery-ui //= require jquery_ujs, I don't get any different result to when they are included

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122561/discussion-between-prashant-ravi-darshan-and-mel).

Comment: When I remove remove //= require_tree . (after reinstating //= require jquery-ui //= require jquery_ujs) I don't get any different result to when it is included

Comment: I can't see how to get ctrl +u to work. It doesnt generate any result

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22977412/2860931 It doesnt feel like an actual solution - but rather a work around. I'll take that as good enough for now. I've tried at least 30 different solutions posted in various places on SO.

Answer (score 1):

U r missing

```
data-toggle="tab"
```

The example of working code:

```
<a href="#tab-guag-content-first" data-toggle="tab">
  <span>MOTIVATION</span>
</a>
...
<a href="#tab-guag-content-second" data-toggle="tab">
  <span>OBJECTIVES</span>
</a>
...
<a href="#tab-guag-content-third" data-toggle="tab">
  <span>VISION</span>
</a>
```

Comment: It all works great when I reorder the application js (so that bootstrap is below jQuery). but then that means the menu doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm going to assume you're using gems to load some of the assets, such as [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails). I say this because if you have the `require_tree .` statement, then all of the files in your `javascripts` will be included automatically. Secondly, try setting up your `application.js` to look something like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require misc-stuff
 *= require jquery-stuff
 *= require bootstrap-stuff
 */
```

I noticed you didn't have a `require_self` statement in the snippet you provided, so that may also have something to do with your problem.

Thirdly, you may have some css problems.

Comment: I have gem 'jquery-rails' and gem 'jquery-ui-rails' in my gem file. Do you mean that I put require tree  and require self at the very top and then all files referencing bootstrap at the very bottom and all files referencing jQuery just above bootstrap with all other files above jQuery?

Comment: Can you give me a clue about the css issues you can see?

Comment: For your first question, yes. That should work. For your second question, I'm not sure. Hence why I said you may have some problems with it. I also noticed you have a bunch of custom javascripts (and I can only assume you have a lot of custom stylesheets as well), so something in those may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Also, try loading stylesheets first and javascripts last in your webpages and see if that helps.

Comment: how can i investigate what is causing this problem with the javascripts? I have tried putting the files in the order you suggested. it doesnt work and several other problems arise when I try it that way. Is there a strategy for investigating how the problems arise with bootstrap that I outlined above.

Comment: Personally, I'd remove everything except JQuery. Then load your views and css and see if everything performs normally. Next, go through your custom js and sprinkle some `print` statements to be sure the code is performing the way you want it. Reload and adjust. Finally, add in Bootstrap. It may be better to use `bootstrap-sass` or `bootstrap-rubygem` instead of `bootstrap-sprockets`. Utilize more prints. It's hard to say discerningly when I don't know your specific setup.

Comment: I use bootstrap sass gems: gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
g

Comment: I can't find the problem im afraid. Every instance of loading jQuery before bootstrap means the bootstrap drop down doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok what you need to is this:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui 
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Now your tab show function works and your menu doesn't, let's fix that aswell.

**Add this script to your page:**

```
<script>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```