# Bootstrap.js not expanding mobile menu on toggle in Rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

My hamburger menu is not expanding even though the .toggled class is being added when I press on the mobile menu. I have played around with the order of the javascript require commands, but the javascript I want doesn't appear to be working.

My efforts:

- `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` seems to be [implemented correctly into Gemfile and into application.scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass)
- Made sure I did `//= require 'jQuery'` `before //= require jquery_ujs` [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974774/rails-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working)

Here are my files for my Rails application:

Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Relevant part of _navigation.html.erb

```
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Brand", root_path , class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo" %>
    </div>
```

Also, if it helps, I am using the [Material Pro UI Kit](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-kit-pro)

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "devise_bootstrap_views";
@import "sass_copy/material-kit";
```

I made sure to delete the bootstrap.js and jquery.min.js files from the Material Pro Assets to make sure I wasn't using the same file twice. Also, there is no bootstrap.scss or .css file to be concerned about. I appreciate the help!

Comment: so this does not work on the desktop google chrome/mozilla responsive version? or it does not work on your mobile? I ask because with chrome you can debug you app on the mobile, connecting a remote devices. Some `jquery` functions do not work on mobile. For example, a couple of days ago I found out that `.focus()` would not work on `remote mobile`, but was ok on the `responsive design debugger`

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio it does not work when I go on my iPhone to try to access it. I am currently running it on heroku for production. If you want to see, here is the URL: bukenstok.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was loading my custom javascript twice which was causing the navigation to toggle twice (so nothing was changing when pressing the hamburger menu). Important lesson behind this: search in your console to see which JavaScript files are dealing with classes that you are having issues with (in my case the toggled class) and see if you have repeated yourself. It will cause problems.